# Error about one or more multiply defined methods in C++

Tags: c++

I am extremely new to C++ and I've been getting this error and I can't find out what is wrong with my code, so I am just going to paste it here and hope someone can help me out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double salesT, countyT, price, totalT;

    salesT = 52 * 0.04;
    countyT = 52 * 0.02;
    price = 52 + salesT + countyT;
    totalT = salesT + countyT;

    cout << "The sales tax of the item is: " << salesT << endl;
    cout << "The county tax of the item is: " << countyT << endl;
    cout << "The total tax of the item is: " << totalT << endl;
    cout << "The purchasing price of the item is: " << price << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the error that I am getting:

```
1>TaxProblem.obj : error LNK2005: _main already defined in Source.obj
1>c:\users\rohan vidyarthi\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Chapter 2
  Exercies\Debug\Chapter 2 Exercies.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more 
  multiply defined symbols found
```

I think it is because I already had one source.cpp and then I wanted to make a new program and I added it to the source and named it Taxproblem, how would I do that?

http://puu.sh/mRqzV/e44628cad2.png

Comment: You can only have one `main` function per program. In Visual C++, a project is a program. Therefore, if you want two programs, you need two projects.

Comment: You have two source files in your project, both apparently defining `main`. There must be only one instance of `main` in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have exactly one `main` per program.

That means: New main -> New project.

Comment: well that is a bummer, thanks.. makes it a lot more tedious :(

Comment: @Panthy Okay, I don't acutally know MSVS, but if creating a project actually is tedious compared to writing the code, you should switch to a better IDE. Given its market share, I doubt MSVS is *that* bad. If you just want to test a couple LOC, you may also use online compilers such as CoLiRu, Wandbox or IDEone.

Answer (score 1):

As you already understand, the problem is in having two `main` functions in one project. 
Answer about creation new project is good, but you should know alternative way, that explain some features of Visual Studio.
So, If you have two cpp-files in one project (e.g. `source.cpp` is old one, and `newcode.cpp` is new one), you can find `source.cpp` with solution explorer and exclude it from project.

To open `solution explorer` use `Ctrl+Alt+L` (or menu View -> Solution Explorer)

To exclude file use context menu from right mouse click and choose `Exclude From Project` (If you created project in correct way, in the solution explorer you will see a tree grows from the root solution and ends with files in folders, you have to find file in folder `Source Files`)

Then `Rebuild Solution`, e.g. with `Ctrl+Alt+F7`

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one main function in a program. Since the control has to start from here and if you have defined more than one main functions, the compiler would throw this linkage error.